# Unable to close modal plugin on form submit

Tags: java, html, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSTv8.jpg)I am using bootstrap modal plugin for an inquiry form and am using "ng-submit" directive to save the details of the form, but when i click on the submit button the form gets submitted but the modal window does not gets closed. How can i close the modal when details have been submitted.

Please find the image for modal reference.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Please provide a functional example of your code, or describe your problem with more accuracy

Comment: Please post the code... We cant read the code if we can't see it!

Comment: it will be better if you provide a plunker link with your code

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the code..

Comment: @VinayMittal Just copy the code and paste it into the question! No need to add screenshots :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick hack around, in your `callBackUser()` method in controller add the below piece of code,

`$('#exampleModal').modal('hide');`

Again not advisable to mix jQuery and Angular.

**EDIT** As per your comments, clear all your form data like this,

`$scope.callback.firstName = "";
$scope.callback.useremail= ""`

And so on.. for all the fields!

Comment: @VinayMittal great!!, if you can upvote the answer :)

Comment: but again the issue is that if I again call for the same modal form, it shows previous data..
i.e on new call form values are not reset

Comment: @VinayMittal clear all the fields in your callback will do the work

Comment: Updating my answer

Comment: Thanks all got this done by using the below in my controller..

    $('#exampleModal').find('form')[0].reset();

Comment: @VinayMittal one more thing as of now your way of clearing is fine. But if in future someone adds one more form before the current form that you have then the fields of newly added form will get cleared but the exixting form fields won't. Follow the pattern as I've said, would be future proof.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary i have reset the form only after successful submit , is that fine?

Comment: @VinayMittal yes that is ok.. but the way you are resetting the fields using `$('#exampleModal').find('form')[0].reset();` is not gooding. It is finding the first form in that modal and then resetting the fields, if in future you or someone else adds one more form above existing the existing form, you will face issues

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary so can i get it done by finding the form with "id" i.e form-id? instead of finding form[0]

Comment: @VinayMittal either form `id` or form `name`

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary can you help me with turnJs

Comment: @VinayMittal Can you please ask a question on it? You can directly ask it to me. I can help.